# Windows 7 desktop shortcut for running java command

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

All I want to create a desktop shortcut that do :

```
start cmd.exe 
D:
cd data-generator
java -cp bitcoin-data.jar com.dev.DoSomething
```

`cmd` should be running after that so that I can see console logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a batch script which runs the commands you stated. To do this, open notepad (or any text editor) and write the commands, with each new line being a new command. Note that you do not need the "start cmd.exe line", and to keep the window open at the end, include a `pause` command. Example contents of your file:

```
D:
cd data-generator
java -cp bitcoin-data.jar com.dev.DoSomething
pause
```

Then, save the file as a .bat

NOTE  That your text editor may try and save the file as a text (.txt) file, so make sure to select the type as "all files" and ensure that the .bat is at the end of the file as shown below.

[image: Example notepad saveas window]

Once you have saved the file, you can double click it to run the commands.

For a more advanced tutorial, check this out: [Batch File Tutorial](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/write-simple-batch-bat-file/)